# When passing post request in vb.net to API controller the request object shows null value

Tags: vb.net

Post () in Controller

Public Function Token(ByVal request As GetTokenRequestType) As GetTokenResponseType

```
        Dim nextCustomer As CreditCardModel = New CreditCardModel()
        Return nextCustomer.GetToken(request)

    End Function
```

Comment: The request object is not getting serialised to GetTokenRequestType class

Comment: Please update me with some feedbacks so that I incorporate it in my application